How to generate apex tests (for old apex classes) with TestDataFactory included
We tried Agentforce to generate some apex tests for old, abandoned apex classes today.
We are pursuing the enablement of a new CI/CD pipeline for our org which has 11-12 years old apex classes developed by dozens of different consulting companies(which ofc long gone).
Goes without saying, for new apex classes we build tests ourselves - it is only for those 300+ apex classes which has low to non quality/quantity tests.
Long story short, we are happy with the first results of Agentforce generated classes but wondering if we can instruct it somehow (or another tool, that's fine too) to use our TestDataFactory when generating those test classes.
If somebody gone through this experiment, it would be useful to read the first findings.

Is this purely for code coverage? If the classes are "abandoned" then why keep them at all?

Some are in use some aren’t. We are a big fan of deleting stuff but it is not always straightforward to not break things when removing dependencies from legacy apps.

It turned out, it is easy enough asking AgentForce to use our own test data factory in prompts. What's more we can even ask to generate new test data factory method in the factory class for objects for example coming from managed packages.
